# Are there examples of cargo being damaged during re-entry?

Tags: reentry, payload

Are there examples of items being brought to or returned to Earth that were damaged in the re-entry process?  For example, lunar samples during Apollo, or something being returned in the Shuttle payload bay?

**Clarification:** I'm looking for a re-entry where the vehicle and any crew returned intact; just the payload was damaged.  Thus, the loss of *Columbia* doesn't count.

Related:

- [When have secondary payloads damaged the primary payload of a launcher?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21500/26446)
- [Worst damage incurred during a rendevouz or docking operation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30164/26446)

Comment: The obvious answer is STS-107's cargo but I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Good point, I will add a clarification.

Comment: Would you count a hard but not disintegrating landing of s spacecraft? I do not know if any such cases exists but are we limited to cases where the spacecraft decent went as planned?

Comment: Does the **Genesis** sample return count?

Comment: @lijat: Yes.  Considering that someone returning cargo probably wants it in good condition, I'd say damage to cargo would require something going wrong.  It might be failing to secure the payload, turbulence, a rough landing, or the spacecraft rolling over.  But a complete failure of the vehicle is outside the scope of this question, and is already covered in other questions.

Comment: @amI: Unmanned missions (e.g. sample return, spy film) are okay, but if there are multiple answers, I would accept a manned mission (e.g. Apollo, Shuttle, Soyuz) over an unmanned mission.

Comment: I don't have a reference for this but friends of mine who've done bio-science research on the ISS say that samples they get returned are often damaged to the point of being useless. This has become a big problem since the shuttle retired, which could provide relatively low-shock entry and landing compared to the Soyuz and Dragon.

Comment: Shuttle’s deceleration was not that much, well less than 2Gs if I recall correctly. Also, there is much less vibrations during entry than during the launch.